# MongoDB service consumes all ram on Windows machine

Tags: windows, mongodb, memory-management

I am using Mongo DB 3.2 with wired tiger storage engine. I am inserting data in which each document has 20k key & values. The data insertion frequency is 1 minute. 
I am observing that after 2 months when size of data is around 90GB the mongod service is consuming all the memory available rendering the system unusable.

I have limited the wiredTigerCachesizeGB to be 1GB which is relevant from the code below but still the issue.

The compressed size of mongodb database is 14GB.

```
db.stats()
{
        "db" : "analyse_db",
        "collections" : 12,
        "objects" : 704061,
        "avgObjSize" : 124359.58095676369,
        "dataSize" : 87556730928,
        "storageSize" : 15406141440,
        "numExtents" : 0,
        "indexes" : 12,
        "indexSize" : 12902400,
        "ok" : 1
}
> db.serverStatus().wiredTiger.cache
{
        "tracked dirty bytes in the cache" : 1761458,
        "tracked bytes belonging to internal pages in the cache" : 189227,
        "bytes currently in the cache" : 7321700,
        "tracked bytes belonging to leaf pages in the cache" : 7132473,
        "maximum bytes configured" : 1073741824,
        "tracked bytes belonging to overflow pages in the cache" : 0,
        "bytes read into cache" : 5791384,
        "bytes written from cache" : 43242,
        "pages evicted by application threads" : 0,
        "checkpoint blocked page eviction" : 0,
        "unmodified pages evicted" : 0,
        "page split during eviction deepened the tree" : 0,
        "modified pages evicted" : 0,
        "pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted" : 0,
        "pages evicted because they exceeded the in-memory maximum" : 0,
        "pages evicted because they had chains of deleted items" : 0,
        "failed eviction of pages that exceeded the in-memory maximum" : 0,
        "hazard pointer blocked page eviction" : 0,
        "internal pages evicted" : 0,
        "maximum page size at eviction" : 0,
        "eviction server candidate queue empty when topping up" : 0,
        "eviction server candidate queue not empty when topping up" : 0,
        "eviction server evicting pages" : 0,
        "eviction server populating queue, but not evicting pages" : 0,
        "eviction server unable to reach eviction goal" : 0,
        "internal pages split during eviction" : 0,
        "leaf pages split during eviction" : 0,
        "pages walked for eviction" : 0,
        "eviction worker thread evicting pages" : 0,
        "in-memory page splits" : 0,
        "in-memory page passed criteria to be split" : 0,
        "lookaside table insert calls" : 0,
        "lookaside table remove calls" : 0,
        "percentage overhead" : 8,
        "tracked dirty pages in the cache" : 15,
        "pages currently held in the cache" : 70,
        "pages read into cache" : 69,
        "pages read into cache requiring lookaside entries" : 0,
        "pages written from cache" : 3,
        "page written requiring lookaside records" : 0,
        "pages written requiring in-memory restoration" : 0
}
```

Whatever I read from this link https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148395/mongodb-using-too-much-memory clearly tells me that size of data would affect RAM consumption. 
Is there any tunable by which I could limit RAM usage of mongodb service irrespective of data size ?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? MongoDB doesn't currently have a tunable to limit its RAM usage. If this is a busy database, then it will use all available RAM to keep up performance, otherwise you'll see disk thrashing. If this is not a busy database, you should not have RAM issues.

Comment: I have 16GB Ram. I am pumping in 1GB of data into the database every day. Does that count for busy ? Also the strange thing is I don't see Mongod process consuming all memory. Due to wiredtigercacheGB parameter the mongod process in task monitor is consuming only 1GB memory but the RAM gets filled almost instantly like 97%. When I stop mongod process then the RAM comes to normal usage i.e 25%.

Comment: I think you're seeing the effect of the filesystem cache. This is managed by the OS, and it will be released when needed by other things.

Comment: If its filesystem cache why does the RAM go up suddenly when I start Mongo Service & come down as soon as I stop it ? Also if its filesystem cache used my MongoDB process why am I not able to see it in task monitor ?

Comment: Filesystem cache is managed by the OS for the whole OS, so it's not tied to a specific process: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache